# Can we add @objc for swift function that returns optional value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a swift method like:

`public func xIndexAtPoint(point: CGPoint) -> Int?`

I want to expose it to Objective-C runtime, so I add @objc before it.

`Method cannot be marked @objc because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C`

I am not sure why optional value is not allowed, since Apple does not 
mention it in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

You’ll have access to anything within a class or protocol that’s marked with the @objc attribute as long as it’s compatible with Objective-C. This excludes Swift-only features such as those listed here:

```
Generics

Tuples

Enumerations defined in Swift

Structures defined in Swift

Top-level functions defined in Swift

Global variables defined in Swift

Typealiases defined in Swift

Swift-style variadics

Nested types

Curried functions
```

Comment: Have you tried with an optional NSNumber instead. Either that or have a non optional int and just return -1 if there was an error e.t.c.

Comment: I need it to return NSInteger in Objective-C runtime.

Comment: But NSInteger is not a class value, so it cannot be nil, as an optional could be.

Comment: It does not matter whether you are returning class type or structure type, optional can be used with any type in swift

Comment: Optional types can be used with Objective-C, the `(nullable)` keyword adds support for this. It is automatically unwrapped in objective c so that an optional that contains null in swift will just be nil/null in objective c

Comment: Obviously Int? cannot be used so just supplement it for either non nullable or perhaps CInt or NSNumber?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Int` is a structure defined in Swift which listed in Swift-only features

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Int_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Si

So the answer is No

you need to break it into two function or some other workaroud

Comment: then which should I use for optional values?

Comment: @Wingzero It's obvious optional value is swift only too. If the plan of Apple is to replace objc with swift in the future there is no need to guarantee every swift function can be called in objc

Comment: well I think objc will live as long ad C, and it cannot be replaced:) I feel there is a long time that a project will be hybrid both objc and swift, until apple only give new API to swift. for old ios developers, objc is more comfortable

Answer (score 0):

An Objective-C function can't return a pointer to an Int. You will need to create a wrapper function like:

```
@objc(xIndexAtPoint:)
public func _xIndexAtPoint(point: CGPoint) -> Int {
    return xIndexAtPoint(point: point) ?? NSNotFound
}
```

Then in Objective-C, you can test for NSNotFound

```
NSInteger i = [foo xIndexAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10)];
if(i == NSNotFound) {
}
```